# comparing values between two text files with python

Tags: python, list, parsing, text, io

I've got two text files that I want to make a new file from.

One file has data that looks like this:  `mf-bom.xyrs`

```
J25 5193.94 -3669.45    90.0    1   1   0.0 0.0 DF40C-100DS-0.4V        1   DF40C-100DS-0.4V
J24 4778.15 -3592.17    270.0   1   1   0.0 0.0 DF40C-100DS-0.4V        1   DF40C-100DS-0.4V
TP47    5232.28 -3688.98    0.0 2   1   0.0 0.0 DO NOT POPULATE     1   DNP
TP19    4905.98 -3583.0 0.0 2   1   0.0 0.0 DO NOT POPULATE     1   DNP
TP15    5206.3  -3796.85    0.0 2   1   0.0 0.0 DO NOT POPULATE     1   DNP
```

and the other has data that looks like this: `single-bom.bom`

```
114.119, 114.119, "R12"
114.633, 114.633, "R25"
117.028, 117.028, "C20"
135.495219, 135.495219, "TP34"
137.56, 137.56, "J24"
147.56, 137.56, "J25"
```

I want to look at the last item in `single-bom.bom` and get the value there...In this case, it's R12.  Then, I want to look at the first entries in each line of `mf-bom.xyrs` and see if there's a match ("R12").  If there is, copy and append that whole line from `mf-bom.xyrs` to another file.

I've tried bringing them both into python with a list (e.g)

```
with open('mf-bom.xyrs') as f:
    mf_bom = f.read().split("\t")
```

But this made a long, 1 dimensional list and didn't preserve the lines (newlines, I mean).

Everything else I've tried is too stupid to post here....I feel like I'm banging my head here and missing the point of how easy python can be if you use it right.

Comment: Look into using something more useful for your application; a list is quite generic, and doesn't give you good search capabilities.  A dict or a PANDAS data frame would likely help.  Read one file into that structure.  Read the other a line at a time, looking for the key in your structure.  When you find a match, dump the newly-formatted line to your output file.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but I wanted to address your attempt to read in the file.

When you do this:

```py
with open('mf-bom.xyrs') as f:
    mf_bom = f.read().split("\t")
```

You're reading in the entire file and then splitting it on tabs...so of course you get one big single list.  You want to split each line of the file independently, so something like this:

```py
with open('mf-bom.xyrs') as f:
    mf_bom = []
    for line in f:
      mf_bom.append(line.split('\t'))
```

After this code, `mf_bom` would be a list of lists, one per line, e.g:

```
[
  ['J25', '5193.94', '-3669.45', '90.0', '1', '1', '0.0', '0.0', 'DF40C-100DS-0.4V', '1', 'DF40C-100DS-0.4V'],
  ...
]
```

You can write that more succinctly like this:

```py
with open('mf-bom.xyrs') as f:
    mf_bom = [line.split('\t') for line in f]
```

You could also use the `csv` module to read this file.